# How to use Laravel commands inside Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I have a textbox that upon click opens a Bootstrap modal while passing a number with it.

However when I am in the modal content page, I can't use any Laravel 4.2 functions.

How can I display a page from Laravel to modal. I am fine in making views or new models.

My main html looks like this:

```
<input type='text' value='EDIT ENTRY' onclick="callModalLotEdit(1);">
<!-- Modals -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then my Javascript function:

```
function callModalLotEntry(ID){
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../app/views/ajaxmodal.blade.php",
        data: "ID=ID",
        success: function(result){
            $('.modal-content').html(result);
            $('#myModal').modal().show();
        }
    } );
}
```

When I am in ajaxmodal.blade.php I have no access to Laravel functions.

Comment: Your ajax is loading your blade template which is only rendered in server. You should have a `POST` route from which your server returns rendered view and you might need to do extra work when using ajax post request to route with `auth` middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a route and return the view

```
Route::post('ajaxmodal', function(){
return View::make('ajaxmodal');
});
```

ajax to that view

```
 url: "{{url('ajaxmodal')}}",
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a function in controller that can return a view to ajax call response as a string. Like this:

```
function callModalLotEntry(ID){
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/getView",
        data: "ID=ID",
        success: function(result){
            $('.modal-content').html(result);
            $('#myModal').modal().show();
        }
    } );
}

Route::get('/getView',[
            'middleware'=>'auth',
            'uses'=>'Controller@getView'
    ]);

function getView()
{
   return view('myView');
}
```